# How can I open UTF-16 files on Python 2.x?

Tags: python, unicode

I'm working on a Python tool that must be able to open files of UTF-8 and UTF-16 encoding.  In Python 3.2, I use the following code to try opening the file using UTF-8, then try it with UTF-16 if there's a unicode error:

```
def readGridFromPath(self, filepath):
    try:
        self.readGridFromFile(open(filepath,'r',encoding='utf-8'))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
            self.readGridFromFile(open(filepath,'r',encoding='utf-16'))
```

(`readGridFromFile` will either run through to completion, or raise a `UnicodeDecodeError`. )

However, when I run this code in Python 2.x, I get:

```
TypeError: 'encoding' is an invalid keyword argument for this function
```

I see in the docs that Python 2.x's `open()` doesn't have an `encoding` keyword.  Is there any way around this that will allow me to make my code Python 2.x compatible?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`io.open` is drop-in replacement for your needs, so code sample you've provided will look as follows in Python 2.x:

```
import io

def readGridFromPath(self, filepath):
    try:
        self.readGridFromFile(io.open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-8'))
    except UnicodeDecodeError:
        self.readGridFromFile(io.open(filepath, 'r', encoding='utf-16'))
```

`io.open` is described [here](http://docs.python.org/library/io.html#io.open) in detail. Its prototype is:

> io.open(*file, mode='r', buffering=-1, **encoding=None**, errors=None, newline=None, closefd=True*)

`io` module itself was designed as compatibility layer between Python 2.x and Python 3.x, to ease transition to Py3k and simplify back-porting and maintenance of existing Python 2.x code.

Also, please note that there can be a caveat using `codecs.open`, as [it works in binary mode **only**](http://docs.python.org/library/codecs.html#codecs.open):

> **Note:** Files are always opened in binary mode, even if no binary mode was specified. This is done to avoid data loss due to encodings using 8-bit values. This means that no automatic conversion of '\n'` is done on reading and writing.

Also you may run into issues of manually detecting and stripping out UTF8 BOM — `codecs.open` leaves UTF8 BOM inline as `u'\ufeff'` character.

Comment: Good call, `io.open` is the better option. However, the disadvantages of `codecs.open` aren't really significant enough to call it "unsuitable", IMHO.

Comment: By the way, the claim about `codecs.open` not handling BOM correctly is just wrong (I tried it). The thing about it not automatically converting newlines is true, though (but this seems to be the only difference).

Comment: I've tried that now again — for UTF-16 BE/LE it works pretty fine, but for UTF8 its BOM (EB BB BF) is left in decoded text as u'\ubeff'. I clearly remember I had decoding problems with BOM using `.decode()` on Windows, but I cannot test it now. I've fixed that claim for fairness.

Comment: \ufeff is the BOM (EF BB BF in UTF-8), and the 'utf-8-sig' codec will detect and strip it if present, as will 'utf16' for UTF-16 encoded text.  'utf-16le' and 'utf-16be' assume no BOM and won't remove it.

Comment: @MarkTolonen, hmmm, seems that [russian wikipedia](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/BOM#.D0.9F.D1.80.D0.B5.D0.B4.D1.81.D1.82.D0.B0.D0.B2.D0.BB.D0.B5.D0.BD.D0.B8.D0.B5_.D0.BA.D0.BE.D0.B4.D0.B8.D1.80.D0.BE.D0.B2.D0.BA.D0.B8_byte_order_marks) tricked me over, as it states **EB** BB BF (**235** 187 191) is UTF8 BOM.

Comment: @modchan: I see the correct `BOM_UTF8` value on [the corresponding page](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8_%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian [here](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/?title=Маркер_последовательности_байтов&diff=next&oldid=42802415) you can see the vandalizing change from March 21st, 2012, that I [had then fixed](https://ru.wikipedia.org/w/?title=Маркер_последовательности_байтов&diff=next&oldid=42805698) in next edit on April 8th, 2012.